# .NET: How to watch memory footprint of an individual object

Tags: .net

Could I use any library programatically to watch memory of an object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [.NET Profiler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188781.aspx) .

or try these tools

- [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) (include a .NET Memory Profiler API wich allows you to automatically detect memory leaks and control the profiler)
- [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ANTS_Memory_Profiler/index.htm)

Bye.

Comment: Whether you know where is the code sample, to use .NET Profiler API with C# to gauge an object's memory.